# Does unique_ptr::release() call the destructor?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Is this code correct?

```
auto v =  make_unique<int>(12);
v.release();     // is this possible?
```

Is it equivalent to `delete` of a raw pointer?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

No, the code causes a memory leak. `release` is used to release ownership of the managed object *without* deleting it:

```
auto v = make_unique<int>(12);  // manages the object
int * raw = v.release();        // pointer to no-longer-managed object
delete raw;                     // needs manual deletion
```

Don't do this unless you have a good reason to juggle raw memory without a safety net.

To delete the object, use `reset`.

```
auto v = make_unique<int>(12);  // manages the object
v.reset();                      // delete the object, leaving v empty
```

Comment: As a completely off topic tangent, I've seen people write `int* raw` and `int *raw`, but that's the first time I've seen `int * raw`

Comment: @Cyber: It's a matter of taste. I don't regard the pointer qualifier as being "attached" to either the type or the variable, so I don't attach it to either.

Comment: If find it sad that they decided to use these function names. Something like `detach` would be much less misleading than `release`.

Comment: @eepp Would that destroy the object or just do like `release`?

Comment: @tuket See its declaration (`operator=()` accepting a `nullptr_t` parameter): _Effectively the same as calling `reset()`_.

Comment: Setting it to nullptr is much less clear and requires knowledge of the argument's meaning.

Comment: I disagree @nenchev.  I think assignment from nullptr is _more_ clear.  There's literally nothing else it could do except delete the pointed-to object (it's unique_ptr) because it's obviously replacing the current value with nullptr.  For reset(), you have to go read the docs to be sure exactly what that function does.

Comment: @MadScientist To be honest, after giving this a second thought, I agree with you. I guess my initial reaction was because reset() seems pretty explicit about resetting the contents of the unique_ptr, whereas setting it to nullptr didn't seem as explicit to me, but there's not much else it could mean now that I think about it.

Comment: A shorthand for your 'release()' version: `delete v.release();`

Comment: `v.get_deleter()(raw);` is better than `delete raw;`

Answer (score 39):

> Is this code correct?

No. Use `std::unique_ptr<>::reset()` to delete the internal raw pointer:

```
auto v =  std::make_unique<int>(12);
v.reset(); // deletes the raw pointer
```

After that is done, `std::unique_ptr<>::get()` will return `nullptr` (unless you provided a non-`nullptr` parameter to `std::unique_ptr<>::reset()`).

Answer (score 32):

> Is this code correct?

It is not, and will leak.

`release()` just lets go of the memory ownership that this `unique_ptr` held until it was called, and returns a pointer that the caller now is responsible for, including having to manually delete it.

If you don't assign the pointer returned by `release()`, you'll just have a leak.

An explicit delete for a `unique_ptr` would be `reset()`. But do remember that `unique_ptr` are there so that you don't have to manage directly the memory they hold. That is, you should know that a `unique_ptr` will safely delete its underlying raw pointer once it goes out of scope.

So you should have a very good reason to perform manual memory management on an automatic memory management object.

Answer (score 14):

`release` will leak your raw pointer since you don't assign it to anything.

It is meant to be used for something like

```
int* x = v.release();
```

Which means `v` is no longer managing the lifetime of that pointer, it is delegating the raw pointer ownership to `x`. If you just `release` without assigning to anything, you leak the raw pointer.

Comment: Ah I see. So in my code I've been using `.get()` followed by `.reset()` to swap things around, but really what I'm wanting to do is `.release()` followed by `.reset()`, to make sure the `.reset()` call doesn't then `delete` the old object. `.release()` then performs the same function as `.get()`, after releasing the pointer.

Comment: or perhaps not `.reset()` but simple assignment post-`.release()`.

Comment: A `.get()` followed by a `.reset()` will cause a problem. The `.get()` will give you a *non-owning* pointer, then `.reset()` will call `delete`, therefore your raw pointer from `get` is now a "dangling pointer" and accessing it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7):

it may be a bit tricky for arbitrary types:

```
  unique_ptr<Foo> v = get_me_some_foo();  // manages the object
  Foo * raw = v.release();        // pointer to no-longer-managed object
  delete raw;
```

is almost correct.

```
  unique_ptr<Foo> v = get_me_some_foo();  // manages the object
  Foo * ptr = v.release();        // pointer to no-longer-managed object
  v.get_deleter() ( ptr );
```

this one would be correct in all situation; there may be a custom deleter defined on type Foo, but using the deleter returned by the unique_ptr object is good for all cases.