# Does unique_ptr release cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++

I'm confused about `unique_ptr.release()`.

My goal is to cast a [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) of a base class to a `unique_ptr` of a derived class.

So I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417848/stdunique-ptr-with-derived-class/17417920?noredirect=1#comment69296901_17417920)
and the answer is

```
Derived *tmp = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePointer.get());
std::unique_ptr<Derived> derivedPointer;
if(tmp != nullptr)
{
    basePointer.release();
    derivedPointer.reset(tmp);
}
```

or

```
std::unique_ptr<Derived>
    derivedPointer(static_cast<Derived*>(basePointer.release()));
```

Then I was wondering what happen to the base pointer after `basePointer.release();`.

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609457/unique-ptr-explicit-delete), I understand that it causes a memory leak.

Am I right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Am I right?

No.

Calling `release()` doesn't leak anything, it just signals that *you are taking control of it*.

If *you* leak a pointer after explicitly releasing it from a smart pointer, that's *your* fault.

Comment: So if I cast the pointer to another unique_ptr, it should be fine then?

Comment: Yep, in your code it behaves exactly as Benjamin indicates - I just went for the general answer rather than the specific.

Comment: No problem at all :)

Answer (score 6):

A memory leak happens when you lose track of the last pointer to a dynamically allocated object before you delete it. Since you copied the pointer to `tmp` first, you didn't lose track of it when you called `release()`. So no, there is no memory leak here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted to make sure.